# Why does ansible parse contents of blockinfile?

Tags: ansible, yaml

... in the end it turned out that all my attempts to debug had gotten the question and my file out of sync. As it was said below, the initial problem was a missing quote, then I had been messing around and had removed the space between block: and the pipe character.  I'll leave this as it may be helpful if anybody else have some problems with blockinfile ...

I am trying to use ansible to set up some raspberries. Everything works fine, until I try to add a static IP. The task is (The hosts and taks

```
- name: Sett opp boom / shake
  hosts: boomshake
  tasks:
  
  (... a number of tasks that works fine ...

- name: Set up static ip
  become: yes
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/dhcpcd.conf
    marker: "# ANSIBLE MANAGED - static ip {mark}"
    block:|
        interface=eth0
        static ip_address=xxx.yyy.zzz.{{lastoct}}/26
        static routers=xxx.yyy.zzz.1
        static domain_name_servers=xxx.yyy.zzz.106,8.8.8.8
  tags: network
```

Lastoct is a variable that is set for each raspberry in the hosts file.

When I run this, I get:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unexpected end of stream
  (...)
The offending line appears to be:
        static domain_name_servers=10.10.1.106,10.10.1.110,8.8.8.8
                                  ^ here
There appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.
```

So ansible is parsing the contents of the block that it just should insert into the file verbatim. How can I stop this from happening?

In my attempt of debugging, I have removed the =s, but then I get

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unexpected end of stream (...)
The offending line appears to be:
  tags: network
  ^ here
```

So it is something with the syntax for blocks in yaml I do not get correct.

Using ansible 2.9.17 on centos7

Comment: `block:|` => `block: |` (white space missing as can be clearly seen in the above syntax highlighted code). Meanwhile, everyone here might miss the actual problem if you report a yaml parsing error without providing the entire yaml file which produced it. Make this [MCVE](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing " after {mark} .Try below .yml it should surely work.

```
  [rohtash@172 blockinfile]$ cat new1.yml 
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      gather_facts: no
      tasks:
      - name: Set up static ip
        become: yes
        blockinfile:
          path: dhcpcd.conf
          marker: "# ANSIBLE MANAGED - static ip {mark}"
          block: |
              interface=eth0
              static ip_address=xxx.yyy.zzz.{{lastoct}}/26
              static routers=xxx.yyy.zzz.1
              static domain_name_servers=xxx.yyy.zzz.106,8.8.8.8
        tags: network
      
      
    [rohtash@172 blockinfile]$ ansible-playbook new1.yml -e 'lastoct=10'
    
    PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    
    TASK [Set up static ip] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost]
    
    PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
    localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Well spotted, but sorry to say it still did not work

Comment: static domain_name_servers=10.10.1.106,10.10.1.110,8.8.8.8 why your error shows this and your block contains  static domain_name_servers=xxx.yyy.zzz.106,8.8.8.8
  tags: network

Comment: Because I was anonymizing the IPs when I copied in the script but forgot it when I pasted in the error message.

Comment: can you tell me exact difference between your blockinfile task and my new1.yml blockinfile task. Since, I have sent you its ansible-playbook run command output too which is giving output changed means no error. It is impossible if task's parameters and content, everything is same and on my ansible setup it is working fine and on yours it is giving error.

Answer (score 1):

There are more problems. Probably the most important one is the quotation of the *marker* string is not closed. Next, the keyword *hosts:* is missing and the keyword *task:* is missing. If you fix it, e.g.

```yaml
- name: Set up static ip
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars:
    lastoct: 101
  tasks:
    - blockinfile:
        path: test-dhcpcd.conf
        marker: "# ANSIBLE MANAGED - static ip {mark}"
        block: |
          interface=eth0
          static ip_address=xxx.yyy.zzz.{{ lastoct }}/26
          static routers=xxx.yyy.zzz.1
          static domain_name_servers=xxx.yyy.zzz.106,8.8.8.8
      tags: network
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat test-dhcpcd.conf 
# ANSIBLE MANAGED - static ip BEGIN
interface=eth0
static ip_address=xxx.yyy.zzz.101/26
static routers=xxx.yyy.zzz.1
static domain_name_servers=xxx.yyy.zzz.106,8.8.8.8
# ANSIBLE MANAGED - static ip END
```

Comment: Well spotted,but sorry to say it did not help (the hosts and task keywords are further up in the file as is a number of tasks that are working if I remove the offending) And I still get the same error with a closing quote

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I can't help without [mre]. Try to isolate the problem.